# Java lotto simulation

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I am writing a program simulating a lotto draw of six numbers between 1 and 45, a sample output is 3 7 12 27 43 28. But what I am trying to do is count the number of times adjacent numbers appear, for example 1 4 5 29 26 41 is a positive answer because 5 comes after 4.

What is the best way of doing that?

I have tried examples such as :

```
int adjacent=0;

    for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
    {
        int t = test[i]+1;
        test[i]=(int)(45*Math.random())+1;

        if(test[i]==t)
            adjacent++;

        System.out.print(test[i]+"    ");
    }
```

This does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the output was `1 4 29 5 26 41`, would you still count the 4 and 5?

Comment: no they would have to be beside each other

Comment: Is the order of the results significant? Can your lotto have repeats?

Comment: Yes the numbers have to go in ascending order eg say 4 was drawn first followed by 5 thats a positive case, no the lotto cant have repeats but I Know how to eliminate that occuring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have an order of operations problem

```
int adjacent=0;

for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
{
    //test[i] hasn't been set yet
    int t = test[i]+1;
    test[i]=(int)(45*Math.random())+1;

    //this comparison doesn't make a whole lot of sense
    if(test[i]==t)
        adjacent++;

    System.out.print(test[i]+"    ");
}
```

Change it around to something like this:

```
int adjacent=0;

for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
{
    test[i]=(int)(45*Math.random())+1;
    int t = -1;
    //Make sure this comparison only happens after the second iteration
    //to avoid index out of bounds
    if ( i != 0 ) 
    {
        //Set t to the last number + 1 instead of trying to predict the future
        t = test[i-1] + 1;
    }
    //Now this comparison makes a little more sense
    //The first iteration will compare to -1 which will always be false
    if(test[i]==t)
        adjacent++;

    System.out.print(test[i]+"    ");
}
```

This can be further simplified to just this:

```
int adjacent=0;

for(int i =0; i<6; i++)
{
    test[i]=(int)(45*Math.random())+1;

    if(i != 0 && test[i]==(test[i-1]+1))
        adjacent++;

    System.out.print(test[i]+"    ");
}
```

Comment: So this will give me a positive result if 8 is drawn followed by 7 for example, or am I misunderstanding the code.

Comment: @user1816464 Should be the opposite, I flubbed a plus sign in the shortened version, it is fixed now.

Comment: Thank You That works now!! Thanks For all your explanation and help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should shuffle it and take any five. `Collections#Shuffle` would help you, It permutes the specified list using a default source of randomness. All permutations occur with approximately equal likelihood.

```
List<Integer> list = ArrayList<Integer>();
list.add(1);
list.add(2);
Collections.shuffle(list);
Random rnd = new Random();
Integer[] result = new Integer[5];
result[0] = list.get(rnd.getNextInt(45));
result[1] = list.get(rnd.getNextInt(45));
result[2] = list.get(rnd.getNextInt(45));
result[3] = list.get(rnd.getNextInt(45));
result[4] = list.get(rnd.getNextInt(45));
```

It always gives you random values, then you should sort it to arrange it in order, say ascending.

```
Arrays.sort(result);
```

now you can write a loop to find out adjacent number.

```
int adjacent = 0;
for(int i=1; i<result.length;i++){
   int prev = result[i-1];
   int now = result[i];
   if(prev+1 == now)
    adjacent++;
}
```

Comment: I am not sure this answers his question. But this is better than using Random to generate the 6 lotto numbers.

Comment: The question is about detecting adjacent values, not about how to generate the random numbers in the first place.

Comment: yes u r , I just want to show the correct way to do it. anyway 'any reason for -ve now '?

Answer (score 0):

After you generate your 6 numbers and put them into an array. Use `Arrays.sort()`. You can then compare adjacent array entries.

You should also avoid using Random to generate you 6 numbers, because it can generate duplicates. This may or may not accurately simulate your lotto draw. Quoi's answer has a good suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to separate the generation of unique (hence the HashSet below to insure identity) random selections, sorting them, and then determining adjacency:

```
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Lotto 
{
    public Lotto()
    {

    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Lotto lotto = new Lotto();
        lotto.randomizeSelections(5);
    }

    private void randomizeSelections(int numOfArrays)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < numOfArrays; i++)
        {
            int[] selArry = new int[6];
            //to insure that each random selection is unique
            HashSet<Integer> idntySet = new HashSet<Integer>();

            for(int j = 0; j < 6;)
            {
                int rndm = (int)(45 * Math.random()) + 1;

                //add selection to the array only if it has not been randomized before
                if(!idntySet.contains(rndm))
                {
                    selArry[j] = rndm;

                    j++;
                }

            }

            //sort the array for determing adjacency
            Arrays.sort(selArry);

            for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                int sel = selArry[j];
                boolean isAdjcnt = (j > 0 && (sel == selArry[j - 1] + 1)) ? true : false;

                System.out.println(i + "." + j + ".random = " + sel);

                if(isAdjcnt) System.out.println("\tAdjacent");

            }
        }
    }
}
```